# How to make a filter so as to have two entries for each user?

Tags: django, django-models

I have model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(user)
    data = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    [...]
```

How to make a filter so as to have result of 10 entries  with two for each user and then all sorted by "user"?

Example:

Display page "users entries" where are the two latest entries per user.

Comment: What is your desired output? Please provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a django newbe, but recently I had similar problem.
Maybe it will make it for You.

I had users based on django User model and Movies with field owner. I wanted to display last 2 movies of every user, grouped by users and sorted by movie publication date.

What I did, was:

- Create and add method to User model (it returns list of 2 movies of user):

  ```
  from django.contrib import auth

  def get_users_last_movies(self):
      movies = Movies.objects.filter(state=3,
               pubdate__lte=datetime.now(), 
               owner=self).order_by('-pubdate')[0:2]
      return movies

  auth.models.User.add_to_class('get_users_last_movies', get_users_last_movies)
  ```
- in view file select all Users your interested in and append their movies to them, use sort method on created user list

  ```
  dusers = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)
  users = []
  for duser in dusers:
      duser.movies = duser.get_users_last_movies()
      users.append(duser)
  users.sort(key=lambda x: x.movies[0].pubdate, reverse=True)
  data['dusers'] = users
  ```

Hope that this code will get You on track